# Is it possible to secure a web page from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript

Detecting and outsmarting an AdBlocker is trivial, but this got me thinking about the issue in terms of a security battle between a page's native script and an extension. In terms of Chrome Extensions, is it possible to protect a user from himself? Lets say the user installs an ad blocker, and its actually stealing his credit card info. Does the web developer have the means to fight the actions of the extension via native page scripts?

Is this fundamentally possible? Why or why not?

Comment: User scripts are generally different than Chrome Extensions. User scripts have a [different API](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php) than Chrome Extension [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). But you seem to be using the words interchangeably. Do you mean one, the other, or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the user script/chrome extension could simply block the script element before it even loaded. A decently designed piece of malware would do this automatically.

Comment: What if you load the script inline?

Comment: You can still disable it. If I curl your webpage I can filter out the script tags, and still display it without scripting, styling, or any dynamic content.

Comment: As Neil mentioned as a comment for the starting post, the API for userscripts and chrome extensions are different. Userscripts usually dont have the possibility to block requests so any kind of embedded JS will always run.

Comment: @JamesCameron it can set the script's innerHtml attribute to ''

Comment: After its been loaded into memory and executed, yes.